# Abstract Algebra- Factor Group Generator Question

Tags: abstract-algebra

So far I have that the factor group is equal to: {(2,1), (1,2), (0,0)}, {(0,1), (2,2), (1,0)}, {(0,2), (2,0), (1,1)}. However, I'm having trouble finding, even understanding what a generator of a factor group is. Is it simply the elements that generate each coset individually? That seems pretty trivial. There is no single element that generates all of the elements in all of these cosets. Does this mean that this factor group is not cyclic?

> 5. Is the factor group $(\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_3)/\langle(2,1)\rangle$ cyclic?  If it is cyclic, then list all of its generators in the form $[(a, b)]$ where $(a,b)\in \Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$.
>      [(original screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPDfk.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Let's just determine what stuff is generated by $(2,1)$ - all the stuff that is identified by the quotient.

$(0,0)$, $(2,1)$, $(1,2)$, and then we're back to where we started. So now the order of the original group is $9$, and the order of the quotient is $9/3 = 3$. This is a prime number, so the group is cyclic.

I'm not familiar with the term 'factor group.' I think what you call 'factor group' I have seen called a 'quotient group.' The generators of the quotient are exactly what you expect - they are the group elements which generate every element of the quotient.

Now if we want to find a generator of this quotient, I like to just kind of think backwards. The quotient is a cyclic group - it is $\mathbb Z_3$. A generator of $\mathbb Z_3$ is just an element $1$. What maps to $1$ under the projection homomorphism? How about the element $(1,0)$? Well $(1,0) + (1,0) = (2,0) = (2,3) = (0,2)$ after taking the quotient, and then adding $(1,0)$ again gives $(1,0)$ which is where we started. So this is a generator of the quotient. This suggests our isomorphism between the quotient and $\mathbb Z_3$ be defined by mapping $(1,0) \mapsto 1$.

Comment: Yes, factor group and quotient group are the same. I understand that the order of the quotient group is 3, but why does the order of the group being prime imply that it is cyclic? I don't see the connection there. From what I understand, we can tell a group is cyclic if all of it's elements can be generated by a single element, but I wasn't aware that if a group had prime order then it was automatically cyclic.

Comment: The order of a subgroup divides the order of a group. So if a group has prime order, the only subgroup is the trivial group. Thus any non-identity element of the group generates the whole group. So the group is cyclic.

Comment: I'm still a little confused though. So we have that our factor group is  {(2,1), (1,2), (0,0)}, {(0,1), (2,2), (1,0)}, {(0,2), (2,0), (1,1)}. Am I correct so far? Now, we're trying to find a single element that generates all of the elements in these 3 sets. I'm not quite sure how (1,0) does this. I follow you all the way up until (1,0) = (2,3), but not sure how (2,3)=(0,2).

Comment: well in $\mathbb Z_3$, we know that $0 = 3$!

Answer (score 0):

Use these two facts to arrive at the answer of the structure of the factor group:

The first fact is about quotients about factor groups -
 $$(G \times H) / (G^\prime \times H^\prime) = (G / G^\prime) \times(H / H^\prime)$$

The second is that $$\langle(2, 1)\rangle = \{ (2n, 1n) : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\} = 2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$$

Combine the two facts together and apply it on $$\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$$

to study the structure of the factor

Comment: You mean $2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, right?